# Restrict user to take photos of object from top view only using camera

Tags: android, camera

how to restrict user to take photos from top view only.
is there any third party lib for this.

I didn't found any help for this yet.

Comment: this question is for android platform as of now

Comment: please explain the question more . what you want to do ?

Comment: Simple image capture with a twist: ensuring user takes photo from directly above any object- not at an angle

Answer (score 0):

Make an overlay for the camera where the User can see if the device is near level. Might want to use [Sensor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html). Not sure if you can parse the data out of the exif if the user does take a picture, to make sure it is taken the way you want.